# What is the direct equivalent of the Motion API from Windows Phone on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to port a Windows phone program to windows 8, but for orientation the Motion API is used to I have lines of code like the following

```
            If Motion.IsSupported Then
            motion = New Motion With {.TimeBetweenUpdates = Me.TargetElapsedTime}
        End If

        If motion IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                motion.Start()
            Catch
            End Try
        End If

        Dim matrix As Matrix = motion.CurrentValue.Attitude.RotationMatrix
```

The closest I could find was OrientationSensor because it provides the rotation matrix.  But I'm not sure since there are other sensors like the inclinometer, accelerometer, and so on.
Which one should I use that would be the most direct port?

Comment: Most phones and tablets have these hardware sensors.  Very few general purpose computers do.  You'll have to use whichever one(s) the hardware has, whether it's your ideal sensor or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrientationSensor` is the equivalent one. It combines data from different sensors, as the Motion API does in Windows Phone.

From the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj155768.aspx):

> If available, the OrientationSensor projection is recommended; if not
>   available, you may combine the accelerometer, gyrometer, and compass
>   to obtain similar results.